# How to force users to complete their profile in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to force users to complete their profile and enter the required informations into their profile before navigating between the other pages in Front with React.
How could i achieve it?!

Comment: That depends on the process you are following. Is it necessary to have a completed profile when the users signs up oder does the user signs up and should later complete its profile?

Comment: Add a variable to localStorage or sessionStorage and when user logins to your app check user data and if it's completed the variable will be true otherwise stays false. In navigation you check the variable and if it's true you let the user to navigate, otherwise redirect user to profile route.

Comment: Alternatively to @davoodSandoghsaz solution you could build your own custom hook which you fill with data right after login that checks if the users profile is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a check (states) before submit and prompt to the user and after that navigate.
Or you can disable some parts if the profile is not completed

Answer (score 0):

you can add required to your input fields and put condition before navigating to other page have check that all field are filled then only they can navigate else u cans how them alert to complete that field.